# How to write a regular expression that will replace a password in a url string?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, passwords

I know that it is bad practice to pass the user's password into the urls and we are going to work towards a better solution, but for now I need to do it this way.

How can I replace a password with regex in a url?

The password could be anywhere in the url after the question mark.

The regex will need to handle cases like this:

API?clientcode=abc&password=123&name=123

API?password=123&name=123

API?name=123&password=123

Here is what I have tried but it doesn't cover all the cases:

```
&?password=(.*)&?

'mystring'.replace(/password=(.*?)&/g, 'password=PLACEHOLDER');
```

I have tried this here:
https://www.regextester.com/index.php?fam=108498

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
\b([?&]?password=)[^&< ]*
```

And replace with,

```
$1PLACEHOLDER
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JTNt7g/3)**

JS code demo,

```js
var arr = ['<html><a>password=abc<a></html>','API?clientcode=abc&password=123&name=123','API?password=123&name=123','API?name=123&password=123','password=JCuLnyAVeAJIjxLIPoyO3WNYyHtBgySrHsQg2MimIgxHDfbg3APuiSJHtPVY4lN&name=123'];

for(s of arr) {
  console.log(s + " --> " + s.replace(/\b([?&]?password=)[^&< ]*/g, '$1PLACEHOLDER'));
}
```

Comment: It works great but it does miss these cases: password=JCuLnyAVeAJIjxLIPoyO3WNYyHtBgySrHsQg2MimIgxHDfbg3APuiSJHtPVY4lN&name=123

Comment: @user1261710: As per your samples in post, this case was not there. But it is very easy to handle that as well. If the URL part can be empty, you can use `^` in alternation to expect other than `?` and `&` and can use this regex `((?:^|[?&])password=)[^&]*`. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/JTNt7g/2)

Comment: How about adding this case too? <html><a>password=abc<a></html>

Comment: @user1261710: Sure, You can use this regex `([?&]?\bpassword=)[^&< ]*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JTNt7g/3)